# Can I map two columns in a one-to-many relationship in Prisma?

Tags: javascript, orm, nestjs, prisma

I'm trying to create a prisma schema, where I have an Order model, and a Client model. I would like to have a one-to-many relation between clients and orders.

I have it working with this Order model:

```
clientId     Client            @relation(fields: [clientId], references: [id])
clientId     Int
```

But wanted to also include the client name. Something like this doesn't work:

```
client       Client            @relation(fields: [clientName, clientId], references: [name, id])
clientName   String
clientId     Int
```

This gives me the error

```
Error validating: The argument `references` must refer to a unique criteria in the related model `Client`. But it is referencing the following fields that are not a unique criteria: name, id
```

Is this something that is possible within the Prisma schema? I can do it with my controller in NestJS, but ideally I would want to be done in the Prisma layer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a `@@unique([name, id])` constraint on the Client model. However, I'm not sure if this is the correct or best way to do this.